# How to get a list of available browsers from selenium hub?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Is there anyway to get a list of available browsers that are registered with the selenium hub using java?  For example I can use my browser to go to the console (ie. www.foobar.com:4444/grid/console)  and that gives me a list of all sessions, but is there anyway I can get that list using java code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can by using the grid API.

1. Identify the proxy id from: http://localhost:4444/grid/console
2. Send the following request: http://localhost:4444/grid/api/proxy?id=**${place_the_id_here}**
3. Process the JSON response.

More information: https://github.com/nicegraham/selenium-grid2-api